# Estimating treatment effect with G computation

Tags: propensity-scores, matching

I used the following code to obtain ATE. Before using the 'marginal effect' package, I examined the coefficients of the model and noticed that the 'symptom' variable has a high standard deviation. Is this due to separation? If separation exists, is the ATE obtained by the following code still valid?
here is the code and it's output:
I wonder if you could help me please

```
 library(quickmatch)
    full.logistic=matchit(vacc ~infBvac+bmi+age + job1  
    + gender + hct4 + >disease+ maritalstatus + edu+symptom +, data=m, >distance="glm",method='Quick',replace=F,discard='none',    estimand='ATE' )
    >data.full.logistic=match.data(full.logistic)
```

'''

```
  fit7 <-glm(hospitalization ~ vacc*(age + job1 + gender + infBvac + >hct4 + disease + maritalstatus  + edu+symptom),data = data.full.logistic, >family = quasibinomial(),weights=weights, maxit=50000)
     summary(fit7)
```

'''

```
     Call:
         > glm(formula = hospitalization ~ vacc * (age + job1 + gender + 
    >    infBvac + hct4 + disease + maritalstatus + edu + symptom), 
    >    family = quasibinomial(), data = data.full.logistic, weights 
         >=weights, maxit = 50000)

         >Deviance Residuals: 
          Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
        -2.9810  -0.0605  -0.0099  -0.0012   6.0185  
'''
        >Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
        >(Intercept)         -7.09987    0.14309 -49.619  < 2e-16 ***
        >vacc                -9.04702    3.13949  -2.882 0.003956 ** 
        >age                  0.04883    0.00214  22.814  < 2e-16 ***
        >job1                 0.09538    0.02458   3.880 0.000105 ***
        >gender              -0.24874    0.07880  -3.157 0.001595 ** 
        >infBvac             -3.97268    0.16806 -23.638  < 2e-16 ***
        >hct4                 1.18187    0.10350  11.418  < 2e-16 ***
        >disease              1.19272    0.05146  23.175  < 2e-16 ***
        >maritalstatus        0.53321    0.08863   6.016 1.79e-09 ***
        >edu                 -0.08474    0.05375  -1.577 0.114870    
        >symptom             25.86211  232.12106   0.111 0.911286    
        >vacc:age             0.06919    0.03796   1.823 0.068377 .  
        >vacc:job1           -0.31674    0.39142  -0.809 0.418387    
        >vacc:gender         -0.53635    1.30119  -0.412 0.680193    
        >vacc:infBvac         4.43521    0.94704   4.683 2.83e-06 ***
        >vacc:hct4           -0.67852    1.09055  -0.622 0.533824    
        >vacc:disease        -0.18003    0.43710  -0.412 0.680431    
        >vacc:maritalstatus   0.21176    1.07400   0.197 0.843694    
        >vacc:edu             0.27514    0.67183   0.410 0.682145    
        >vacc:symptom         8.01153  556.07176   0.014 0.988505    
        ''''
'''
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

        >(Dispersion parameter for quasibinomial family taken to be                         1.005116)

         >   Null deviance: 146967.6  on 150800  degrees of freedom
        >Residual deviance:   6954.2  on 150781  degrees of freedom
        >AIC: NA

>Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 22  
'''
>'''
>



    >library(marginaleffects)
>          avg_comparisons(fit7, variables = "vacc",
           vcov = ~subclass,
           newdata = data.full.logistic,
           wts = "weights",comparison = "lnoravg",
           transform = "exp")
'''
>         Term              Contrast Estimate Pr(>|z|)     S 2.5 % 97.5 %
>         vacc ln(odds(1) / odds(0))    0.936   <0.001 543.8 0.932  0.941
```

Comment: You're almost certainly suffering from quasi separation.  A log odds ratio of 25 is enormous, and the associated standard deviation is also very big.  marginaleffects supports  logistf models.  You could try fitting a logistic regression with firth's correction and then estimate the ATE.

Comment: I used logistf package now and the code had this warning        
1: In logistpl(x, y, beta, i, LL.0, firth, -1, offset, weight,  ... :
  fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred for variable (Intercept)

Comment: What exactly is “symptom” and how does it relate to the outcome? What is the outcome

Comment: It's important to know the scale of the variable. If one unit is tiny, then an OR of 25 might not mean anything at all.

Comment: symptom is the number of covid19 symptoms and outcome is hospitalization and is binary variable.